# Unsure how i load the right data into a tableview, chosen from a previous tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uitableview

I currently have two TableViewControllers. The first has seven objects, each day-name listed.

```
Weekdays *mandag = [[Weekdays alloc] initWithName:@"Mandag" daylist:mondayArray];
Weekdays *tirsdag = [[Weekdays alloc] initWithName:@"Tirsdag" daylist:tuesdayArray];
Weekdays *onsdag = [[Weekdays alloc] initWithName:@"Onsdag" daylist:wedensdayArray];
Weekdays *torsdag = [[Weekdays alloc] initWithName:@"Torsdag" daylist:thursdayArray];
Weekdays *fredag = [[Weekdays alloc] initWithName:@"Fredag" daylist:fridayArray];
Weekdays *lordag = [[Weekdays alloc] initWithName:@"Lørdag" daylist:saturdayArray];
Weekdays *sondag = [[Weekdays alloc] initWithName:@"Søndag" daylist:sundayArray];
```

daylist being a NSMutableArray. The idea is: The name of the day is displayed on table-1. And the array (daylist) of each day is displayed on table-2 - when tabbed one a day. The first table, displaying the names is working fine:

```
VisueltSkemaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (VisueltSkemaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
Weekdays *ugeDag = (Weekdays *)[appDelegate.ugeDage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   
cell.textLabel.text = ugeDag.name;
return cell;
```

However i thought i could do the same, for the second table - but i have been strugling with it for hours now. This is what i got:

```
VisueltSkemaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (VisueltSkemaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
Weekdays *ugeDag = (Weekdays *)[appDelegate.ugeDage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [ugeDag.daylist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

Abit more of the code: http://pastebin.com/iW5AAJXt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define property for day list in `InfoTable` (BTW it's better to name this controller like InfoTableController). When you select date in `RootViewController` set this property to selected day's list.

```
// Next line is from your code 
InfoTable *viewController = [[InfoTable alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoTable" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
viewController.dayList = ugeDag.daylist;
...
```

Now you can use it in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of `InfoTable`

```
cell.textLabel.text = [daylist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: You just saved my whole night. Thanks alot, Hoha.